# Multiple between condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I know how to Use between condition in stored procedure.
But my current problem is here.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Talents]
    WHERE

    ((DATEDIFF(YEAR,Talents.DOB,GETDATE()) Between 
    (       
        SELECT dbo.AgeRange.AgeFrom
        FROM dbo.AgeRange
        WHERE
        ((@age_id is null) or (@age_id='') or ([dbo].AgeRange.ID IN
            (
                SELECT CAST (Item as int) FROM dbo.SplitString(@age_id,',')
            )
        ))
    ) 
    AND
    (       
        SELECT dbo.AgeRange.AgeTo
        FROM dbo.AgeRange
        WHERE
        ((@age_id is null) or (@age_id='') or ([dbo].AgeRange.ID IN
            (
                SELECT CAST (Item as int) FROM dbo.SplitString(@age_id,',')
            )
        ))
    )
    )
    )
END
```

It will return correct result if there is 1 value. I mean

```
Between 0 And 9
```

How can I do, if there're many between clause

```
Between 0 and 9

OR

Between 20 and 30
```

I know to use OR in this case. But I don't know how to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here how about this way?

```
DECLARE @flds AS VARCHAR(MAX) --Multi-values
DECLARE @fld AS VARCHAR(MAX) --for One value
SET @flds = '13,67,89,105,203'--Multi-values


DECLARE Recs CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
SELECT VALUE FROM StringSplit(@flds, ',')
OPEN Recs
FETCH Recs INTO @fld
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    IF ((@fld IS NOT NULL)
        IF ((@fld IS NOT NULL) AND (@fld between 10 and 20))
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM test WHERE (fld between 10 and 10) --For 13
        END
        IF ((@fld IS NOT NULL) AND (@fld between 60 and 70))
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM test WHERE (fld between 60 and 70) ... --For 67
        END
        IF ((@fld IS NOT NULL) AND (@fld between 80 and 90))
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM test WHERE (fld between 80 and 90) --For 89
        END
        IF ((@fld IS NOT NULL) AND (@fld between 100 and 200))
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM test WHERE (fld between 100 and 200) ... --For 105
        END
        IF ((@fld IS NOT NULL) AND (@fld between 200 and 300))
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM test WHERE (fld between 200 and 300) ... --For 203
        END
        FETCH Recs INTO @fld
    END
END
CLOSE Recs
DEALLOCATE Recs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE (fld between 0 and 9) OR (fld between 20 and 30);
```

Comment: IF more than 2 conditions, How can I do?
This between condition values come dynamically so...?